# Entity Framework Linq SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, linq

Im facing an issue in entity framework with Linq queries.
I have a query which when I run it give this exception

> "SqlException: The query has been canceled because the estimated cost
> of this query (3010) exceeds the configured threshold of 3000. Contact
> the system administrator"

the server default value for `QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` is `3000` as it shows in the error. I want to change it and make it higher for that particular query since I can not change the default value of the server.

so my question is how do you set `QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` value in entity framework Linq syntax.

I have already tried and added this `db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 15000");`
before my query but it does not work since if im not mistaken `QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` will work for the same query not 2 different queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT is changing limit for current DB connection so you need to be sure that both SQLs are using same connection.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    // open connection
    context.Database.Connection.Open();

    // set limit
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 15000");

    // run query with same connection
    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<...>("SELECT * ");

}
```

Comment: even though this did not solve my issue but i mark it as correct answer as the issue seems to be caused by different thing because sometimes this solution and my solution work and sometimes does not.